# How do I set listeners on an array of objects?

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, listener

I am refactoring an Android app of mine. In the initial version I instantiated eight objects of the same class in the main activity and set listeners separately onto them. For each instance I initialized a separate variable.
Now I want to add the objects to an array and set listeners in the loop, but when I test the app the listener is set only on the last instance.

```
    mObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    mObjects.add(createNewObject(R.id.objectPlaceholder1, R.id.objectProgressTextView));
    mObjects.add(createNewObject(R.id.objectPlaceholder2, R.id.object2ProgressTextView));
    mObjects.add(createNewObject(R.id.objectPlaceholder3, R.id.object3ProgressTextView));
    mObjects.add(createNewObject(R.id.objectPlaceholder4, R.id.object4ProgressTextView));
    mObjects.add(createNewObject(R.id.objectPlaceholder5, R.id.object5ProgressTextView));
    mObjects.add(createNewObject(R.id.objectPlaceholder6, R.id.object6ProgressTextView));
    mObjects.add(createNewObject(R.id.objectPlaceholder7, R.id.object7ProgressTextView));
    mObjects.add(createNewObject(R.id.objectPlaceholder8, R.id.object8ProgressTextView));

    for (int i = 0; i < mObjects.size(); ++i) {
        object = mObjects.get(i);
        object.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                countDownEditText = findViewById(R.id.countdownEditText);
                if (countDownEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    showToastText(R.string.count_down_time);
                    return;
                }
                if (object.checkReadyForAction()) {
                    countDownTime = Integer.parseInt(countDownEditText.getText().toString());
                    object.startCountDown(countDownTime);
                } else {
                    showToastText(R.string.action_not_ready);
                }
            }
        });
        object.image.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                object.reset();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried

Comment: Code, please. Really hard to guess without code

Comment: @Fantômas Why have you changed the title? I want to set listeners on each object in the array.

Comment: ... and... what does it change to the meaning? you don't have to repeat TAGS in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got it working. Just implemented the needed listeners.

```
    // ...

    for (int i = 0; i < mObjects.size(); ++i) {
        object = mObjects.get(i);
        object.image.setOnClickListener(new ObjectClickListener(object));
        object.image.setOnLongClickListener(new ObjectLongClickListener(object));
    }

    private class ObjectClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        ExampleObject mObject;

        ObjectClickListener(ExampleObject object) {
            mObject = object;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            countDownEditText = findViewById(R.id.countdownEditText);
            if (countDownEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                showToastText(R.string.count_down_time);
                return;
            }
            if (mObject.checkReadyForAction()) {
                countDownTime = Integer.parseInt(countDownEditText.getText().toString());
                mObject.startCountDown(countDownTime);
            } else {
                showToastText(R.string.action_not_ready);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ObjectLongClickListener implements View.OnLongClickListener {

        ExampleObject mObject;

        ObjectLongClickListener(ExampleObject object) {
            mObject = object;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            mObject.reset();
            return true;
        }
    }
```